# Can I find cocoa modem in the repositories?

Tags: 14.04, repository, external-soundcard, ham-radio

I just have a basic question. I am trying to set up a digital ham radio station. I have a piece of equipment called a SignalLink, a radio and a computer. What I am trying to do is make it so that the sound card in my computer recognizes the hardware. I saw this youtube video, and it looks like it may work. This is the link-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F9vrDZc7fc. The only thing is he says that you have to have a Mac for cocoa modem. Is there a repository for it? Thank you very much in advance, you have all been very helpful over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [CocoaModem page](http://www.w7ay.net/site/Applications/cocoaModem/index.html), you cannot use it on anything other than OS X, no. It is only available on OS X, and the *Cocoa* in the name is a reference to the core toolkit framework of OS X.